# Why is my Auto Layout layout ambiguous if I don't specify an intrinsic content size for a view that only holds other views also laid out w/AL?

Tags: macos, cocoa, autolayout

I want to provide a standard spinbox (NSTextField + NSStepper combination), but in order to properly use them within custom layout containers I'm also writing (like NSStackView but different in semantics), I need to combine them into a single view. So I've done so, using Auto Layout:

- `H:|[textField]-[stepper]|` to arrange the controls horizontally
- `V:|[textField]|` and `V:|[stepper]|` to bind the controls to the top and bottom of the parent view
- set both text field and stepper's vertical hugging priority to `NSLayoutPriorityDefaultLow` to allow the spinbox to be resized vertically (primarily for testing the behavior of my custom layout containers)

In the test program below, there are two of these spinbox views arranged vertically in the window. The one on the top is made non-stretchy, so (I would assume) it should stay at the intrinsic size of the text field/stepper. The one on the bottom is made stretchy, so it grows and shrinks when you resize the window vertically. This is done as so:

- `V:|-[spinbox1]-[spinbox2]-|` to arrange the controls vertically
- `H:|-[textField]-|` and `H:|-[stepper]-|` to bind the controls to the left and right of the window
- set the upper spinbox's vertical hugging priority to `NSLayoutPriorityDefaultHigh` to force it to not resized vertically
- set the lower spinbox's vertical hugging priority to `NSLayoutPriorityDefaultLow` to allow it to be resized vertically

In the example below, I use a button instead of a text field as a button has an intrinsic content size in both dimensions. The results are the same either way.

The problem is that this layout is ambiguous, and I'm not sure what's going on. Initially, the two spinboxes are not positioned correctly; a window resize or ambiguity exercise fixes this. But after that, I can't change the layout visually no matter how many times I exercise ambiguity. Everything stays in place, so I don't know what changed.

But if I change the view that holds the text field/button and stepper into one that returns an intrinsic content size, the ambiguity goes away! You can do this by passing `unambiguous` as the first argument on the program's command line.

So my questions are twofold:

1. Why is this layout ambiguous? Why do I need an intrinsic content size on the container view; isn't that its subviews are arranged using Auto Layout enough to make things unambiguous? Especially since the tail views of the view hierarchy in this case all have intrinsic widths and heights (which is why I use a button in the below example)?
2. Since this is a container view, I'm assuming that the intrinsic content size should be the union of the intrinsic content sizes of its subviews. But that conflicts with Apple's definition of intrinsic content size, which says it should only consider sizes that Auto Layout can't know about, such as text sizes. (The program below uses a fixed intrinsic content size.) Am I misunderstanding something? Or is my case a special case and I should make the intrinsic content size based on those of my subviews? What does NSStackView do?

This program is a Swift 1.2 program and I tested this on OS X 10.10.

Thanks, and I hope this explanation and my questions were clear.

```
// 9 august 2015
import Cocoa

var makeUnambiguous: Bool = false

var keepAliveMainwin: NSWindow? = nil

// the swift bridge isn't perfect; it won't recognize these properly
// thanks to Eridius in freenode/#swift-lang
let myNSLayoutPriorityRequired: NSLayoutPriority = 1000
let myNSLayoutPriorityDefaultHigh: NSLayoutPriority = 750
let myNSLayoutPriorityDragThatCanResizeWindow: NSLayoutPriority = 510
let myNSLayoutPriorityWindowSizeStayPut: NSLayoutPriority = 500
let myNSLayoutPriorityDragThatCannotResizeWindow: NSLayoutPriority = 490
let myNSLayoutPriorityDefaultLow: NSLayoutPriority = 250
let myNSLayoutPriorityFittingSizeCompression: NSLayoutPriority = 50

var nButton = 1

func appLaunched() {
    var mainwin = NSWindow(
        contentRect: NSMakeRect(0, 0, 320, 240),
        styleMask: (NSTitledWindowMask | NSClosableWindowMask | NSMiniaturizableWindowMask | NSResizableWindowMask),
        backing: NSBackingStoreType.Buffered,
        defer: true)
    var contentView = mainwin.contentView as! NSView

    var spinbox1 = mkSpinbox()
    makeVerticallyNotStretchy(spinbox1)
    contentView.addSubview(spinbox1)
    var spinbox2 = mkSpinbox()
    makeVerticallyStretchy(spinbox2)
    contentView.addSubview(spinbox2)

    var views = [
        "spinbox1": spinbox1,
        "spinbox2": spinbox2,
    ]
    addConstraints(contentView, "V:|-[spinbox1]-[spinbox2]-|", views)
    addConstraints(contentView, "H:|-[spinbox1]-|", views)
    addConstraints(contentView, "H:|-[spinbox2]-|", views)

    mainwin.cascadeTopLeftFromPoint(NSMakePoint(20, 20))
    mainwin.makeKeyAndOrderFront(mainwin)
    isAmbiguous(contentView, 0)
    keepAliveMainwin = mainwin
}

class IntrinsicSizeView : NSView {
    override var intrinsicContentSize: NSSize {
        get {
            return NSMakeSize(96, 30)
        }
    }
}

func mkSpinbox() -> NSView {
    var view = NSView(frame: NSZeroRect)
    if makeUnambiguous {
        view = IntrinsicSizeView(frame: NSZeroRect)
    }
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    var t = mkButton()//mkTextField()
    var s = mkStepper()
    view.addSubview(t)
    view.addSubview(s)
    makeVerticallyStretchy(t)
    makeVerticallyStretchy(s)
    var views = [
        "t":    t,
        "s":    s,
    ]
    addConstraints(view, "H:|[t]-[s]|", views)
    addConstraints(view, "V:|[t]|", views)
    addConstraints(view, "V:|[s]|", views)
    return view
}

func isAmbiguous(view: NSView, indent: Int) {
    var s = String(count: indent, repeatedValue: " " as Character)
    if view.hasAmbiguousLayout {
        view.window?.visualizeConstraints(view.superview!.constraints)
    }
    for subview in view.subviews {
        isAmbiguous(subview as! NSView, indent + 1)
    }
}

// TODO why can't the lets above be here?

func makeVerticallyNotStretchy(view: NSView) {
    view.setContentHuggingPriority(myNSLayoutPriorityDefaultHigh, forOrientation: NSLayoutConstraintOrientation.Vertical)
}

func makeVerticallyStretchy(view: NSView) {
    view.setContentHuggingPriority(myNSLayoutPriorityDefaultLow, forOrientation: NSLayoutConstraintOrientation.Vertical)
}

func addConstraints(view: NSView, constraint: String, views: [String: NSView]) {
    var constraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        constraint,
        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0),
        metrics: nil,
        views: views)
    view.addConstraints(constraints)
}

func mkButton() -> NSButton {
    var b = NSButton(frame: NSZeroRect)
    b.title = "Button \(nButton)"
    nButton++
    b.setButtonType(NSButtonType.MomentaryPushInButton)
    b.bordered = true
    b.bezelStyle = NSBezelStyle.RoundedBezelStyle
    b.font = NSFont.systemFontOfSize(NSFont.systemFontSizeForControlSize(NSControlSize.RegularControlSize))
    b.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return b
}

func mkTextField() -> NSTextField {
    var cell: NSTextFieldCell

    var t = NSTextField(frame: NSZeroRect)
    t.selectable = true
    t.font = NSFont.systemFontOfSize(NSFont.systemFontSizeForControlSize(NSControlSize.RegularControlSize))
    t.bordered = false
    t.bezelStyle = NSTextFieldBezelStyle.SquareBezel
    t.bezeled = true
    cell = t.cell() as! NSTextFieldCell
    cell.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByClipping
    cell.scrollable = true
    t.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return t
}

func mkStepper() -> NSStepper {
    var s = NSStepper(frame: NSZeroRect)
    s.increment = 1
    s.valueWraps = false
    s.autorepeat = true
    s.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return s
}

class appDelegate : NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(note: NSNotification) {
        appLaunched()
    }

    func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(app: NSApplication) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}

func main() {
    makeUnambiguous = Process.arguments.count > 1 && Process.arguments[1] == "unambiguous"

    var app = NSApplication.sharedApplication()
    app.setActivationPolicy(NSApplicationActivationPolicy.Regular)
    // NSApplication.delegate is weak; if we don't use the temporary variable, the delegate will die before it's used
    var delegate = appDelegate()
    app.delegate = delegate
    app.run()
}

main()
```

Comment: If a view doesn't have an intrinsic size in a particular orientation, then its content hugging and compression resistance priorities in that orientation are meaningless. Those priorities are strictly in regards to the intrinsic size. So, setting your spinboxes to stretchy or non-stretchy is meaningless. Haven't checked further, but if two views which do have intrinsic size have the same priority in a given orientation, then that can lead to ambiguity. E.g., if the system needs to compress one or the other but their compression resistance is the same, it's ambiguous which it will compress.

Comment: That's good to know; thanks. I wonder if there's an easier way to tell which constraints were ambiguous, and what visual format they came from, if any... That also raises the question of what I would need to do to make this spinbox unambiguous, and then my other layouts when I stress-test them more thoroughly.